# scrollTo plugin doesn't seem to identify div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollto

The following is my code. I am trying to scroll from once the submit button is clicked to `new-products` . However , the below script doesn't seem to work.

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Ratings" class="main-search-submit" id="go">
    </div>
    <div id="new-products">

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){  
      $(".main-search-submit").click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($("#new-products"), { duration: 0});
      });
    </script>
    <!-- Javascipt Libraries-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Also css of my `new-products` class for test purposes is :

```
#new-products {
    height: 2000px;

}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT: Console shows ->

```
index.html:7 GET file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:9 GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:22 GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:23 GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:24 GET file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:26 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

UPD 1: Adding `http:` before links helped eliminate console errors. But the div still doesn't scroll .

Comment: Maybe your divs are overlapping. Post css here.

Answer (score 1):

Your script has to go after jQuery and the plugins, otherwise jQuery is not available (nor are the plugins)

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Ratings" class="main-search-submit" id="go">

<div id="new-products"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){  
          $(".main-search-submit").click(function() {
              $.scrollTo($("#new-products"), { duration: 0});
          });
      });

</script>
```

Also, you forgot to close the `document.ready` function !

Comment: it shows ` Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/1.4.11/jquery.scrollTo.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:30 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of inpu`

Comment: Your problem is with closing document.ready function  as indicated in the answer!

Comment: Then the CDN fails to load the resources you need, and the plugins are loaded correctly.

Comment: Oh, you're not using a **WEBSERVER**, you're running this from the file system, and that will never work. Download WAMP or something similar.

Answer (score -1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qVWuv/204/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
    $(document).on('click',".main-search-submit",function() {
       $('body').animate({scrollTop : $("#new-products").offset().top}, 100);
    });
 });
```

Comment: nope. doesn't work. console shows that all the CDN are not able to load the libraries. i mean how can it be possible .

Comment: @SamuelFerigyu add the `http://` protocol also you don't have a closing of `doc ready` block and change the stack order of your scripts as suggested by adeneo.

Comment: Yes, thanks that helped eliminate the console errors. But the div still doesn't slide !?

Comment: What am i supposed to check in that ?

Comment: to check the animate scroll code how it works .. I update my answer with new demo  you can check it .. if that what you want?